# retrieve rgb from kinect pointcloud

Tags: kinect, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
The pointcloud published at camera/rgb/points is sensed to have the rgb at the fourth float

```
rostopic echo /camera/rgb/points/fields
- 
  name: x
  offset: 0
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
- 
  name: y
  offset: 4
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
- 
  name: z
  offset: 8
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
- 
  name: rgb
  offset: 16
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
---
```

However, when storing the float with

```
 float *pstep2 = (float*)&msg->data[(kk) * msg->point_step];
      xi[kk] = pstep2[0]; //x
      yi[kk] = pstep2[1]; //y
      zi[kk] = pstep2[2]; //z
      ci[kk] = pstep2[3]; //rgb
```

and printing out the float shows how all of them are set to zero.

How can we retrieve the associated rgb values for each 3d point of the pointcloud output by the kinect?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10199/retrieve-rgb-from-kinect-pointcloud/) by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 169 on 2011-06-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, we knew that, but the float should be non-zero anyway. Actually using the union

```
typedef union
  {
    struct /*anonymous*/
    {
      unsigned char Blue;
      unsigned char Green;
      unsigned char Red;
      unsigned char Alpha;
    };
    float float_value;
    long long_value;
  } RGBValue;
```

returned binary invalid types. But we've solved it converting it first to PointXYZRGB

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::iterator pt_iter = this->pcl_xyzrgb.begin();
for (int rr = 0; rr < (int)pcl_xyzrgb.height; ++rr) {
  for (int cc = 0; cc < (int)pcl_xyzrgb.width; ++cc, ++pt_iter) {
    pcl::PointXYZRGB &pt = *pt_iter;
    RGBValue color;
    color.float_value= pt.rgb;
    matlab_xyzrgb << rr << " " << cc << " " << pt.x*1000 << " " << pt.y*1000 << " " << pt.z*1000 << " " << (int)color.Red << " " << (int)color.Green << " " << (int)color.Blue << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The code above works.

---

Originally posted by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) with karma: 169 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rgb value is stored in just one single float. You can, for instance, use a function like this to decode it:

```
void getRGB(float rgb_encoded, unsigned char &r, unsigned char &g, unsigned char &b)
{
  const unsigned char *color = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(&rgb_encoded);
  r = color[2];
  g = color[1];
  b = color[0];
}
```

When passing `*pstep2` of your example as first parameter, you should get correct rgb values.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2